# Accessing data POST'd to a python AWS Lambda Function URL

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm attempting to invoke an AWS Lambda Function URL in Python. Using their [example lambda code](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/example_code/lambda/lambda_handler_basic.py) as follows the value for `action` is always returning `null`. How do I access the value in the json data I POST to the Function URL?

Lambda Code (taken from [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/example_code/lambda/lambda_handler_basic.py)):

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    result = None
    action = event.get('action')
    if action == 'increment':
        result = event.get('number', 0) + 1
        logger.info('Calculated result of %s', result)
    else:
        logger.error("%s is not a valid action.", action)

    response = {'result': result}
    return response
```

Invoking using a Function URL

```
curl -X POST 'https://[redacted].lambda-url.eu-west-1.on.aws/' -d '{"action":"increment","number": 3}'
```

Result:

```
{"result":null}
```

Problem:

How do I reference the value of `'action'` correctly to produce the `result`?

Comment: I would make this the very first line in the handler function: `print(event)` then call the function one more time, and check the logs. The POSTed data is only going to be part of the `event` object that is passed into the function. Printing the event will allow you to see the entire event object and will show you how you need to access the `action` parameter you are passing in. Also, I recommend reading the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html

Comment: ah - thanks that helped. It turns out the `body` is base64 encoded which contains the POST'd data. Appreciate the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, this is how I adapted the AWS sample code to parse the required fields

```
import logging
import json

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = json.loads(event['body'])
    result = None
    action = message['action']
    if action == 'increment':
        result = message['number'] + 1
        logger.info('Calculated result of %s', result)
    else:
        logger.error("%s is not a valid action.", action)

    response = {'result': result}
    return response
```